# Open page in new tab when dialog closed and request != DELETE

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am using APEX 21.1. I have a report and a form. The form is dialog And is for creating and editing `DEPT` table's data. The report for displaying the same table's data. I should be able to open a page in a new tab after the dialog closes and the request was CREATE or SAVE. If the request is DELETE, the page should not open. The code for opening a new page in a new tab is in the report page's Dialog closed dynamic action. For example, run the report> edit a record> the click Apply Changes> the dialog is closed> the page is opened in a new tab. That was case one. Case 2: instead of clicking Apply changes, click delete to delete the record> the dialog closes> nothing happens.

```
ws= ESLAM_WS
un= forhelp  
pwd= Forhelppwd$  
app= Help  
pages= 2 and 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a page item P3_REQUEST and a process in the dialog page before the "Close Dialog" process to set that item with the request :P3_REQUEST := :REQUEST; and used the dialog return item attribute to return that value. And created another item in the calling page and a set value dynamic action to set it's value with the request value returned. Then set a client-side condition for the DA that calls the new page in new tab. Your answer was very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can use `REQUEST` for that. Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_sub.htm#BEIFJJBC) - 2.7.2.27.2 *... The value of REQUEST is available during each phase of the Accept processing. Once an application branches to a different page then REQUEST is set to NULL.* So if you perform a *DELETE* request on the dialog, then the report will not know about that request value if the dialog page is closed. You could set a page item to that request value in the dialog page, return it to the calling page and have your dynamic action listen on change of that item.

So you'd create a page item P3_REQUEST and a process in the dialog page before the "Close Dialog" process to set that item with the request `:P3_REQUEST := :REQUEST`. Then use the dialog return item attribute to return that value. Create another item in the calling page and a set value dynamic action to set it's value with the request value returned. Then set a client-side condition for the DA that calls the new page in new tab.